# Is there any way of creating a Tree Map with "clickable cells" in Google Data Studio?

Tags: data-visualization, looker-studio, treemap

I have this problem: need to create a Tree Map in Google Data Studio, but every "cell" should be clickable and redirect to another tab/link.

Is this possible? I checked the docs but couldn't find an official answer. Looking for a workaround!

Answer (score 1):

As of now Google Data Studio does not provide such feature. So One data source per page in report that's its limitation.

Although you can create one (But this will not be a Tree Map you have to create it manually) with the help of text boxes and hyper links present in data studio.

Checkout this [sample report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/0f0fb1f7-d930-44b4-9b57-158b12644c50/page/p_pr7cue5qnc)